# purpose of status.php in magento2

Tags: magento2

Not sure if this qualify as a question at all. But as i am unaware of this hence asking.

If you go to `http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php` and create a magento2 module with a `Single Table Model` you will get a zip folder. And after extracting it you will find all the relevant files.

Now if you go inside model folder you will find this.

[image]

Where `New` is the model name.

Here is how its created [image]

If i open `status.php` i can see few lines of code.

```
<?php

namespace SilkSoftware1\ModuleName1\Model;

class Status
{
    /**#@+
     * Status values
     */
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

    const STATUS_DISABLED = 2;

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array with empty value
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option text by option value
     *
     * @param string $optionId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($optionId)
    {
        $options = self::getOptionArray();

        return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
    }
}
```

Have anyone used slik for creating modules and any idea why this `status.php` exists.

Thanks

Comment: it is just for Enabled / Disabled option  value and label

Comment: @MineshPatel for which options? I dont have any options at all. And its not even getting used anywhere.

Comment: just status flag like Yes / No . if you don't have any flag field in DB Table you can remove this file as well

Comment: @MineshPatel can you show some code how do i use this file if i have any such fields in my table.

Comment: you can use this in your grid to show "Text" against "int" values and in your form as select option. it simple i am not sure why  you  stuck in this silly point